# WPF - Dependency Property Initialisation

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I'm trying to implement a WPF component that projects an image onto a 3D model. To make it neater to use, I'm attempting to use a dependency property so that I can bind on the control from my View in the following manner:

```
<viewers:MyViewer
    ProjectedImageSource="{Binding ViewModel.ProjectedSource}"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=HueMapVisible, Converter={StaticResource booleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
    />
```

The control is as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImageProjector.Controls.Viewers.MyViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <LayoutGrid>
        <Viewport3D Name="Viewport" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.RowSpan="7" />
    </LayoutGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Codebehind:

```
public interface IMyViewer { }

public partial class MyViewer : UserControl, IMyViewer
{
    private IImageModel3D imageModel3D;

    public MyViewer() : this(Ninjector.Get<IImageModel3D>()){ }

    public MyViewer(IImageModel3D imageModel3D)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.ProjectedImageSource.Changed += ProjectedImageSource_Changed;
    }

    private void ProjectedImageSource_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imageModel3D.SetImage((BitmapImage)sender);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectedImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                                    "ProjectedImageSource",
                                                                    typeof(BitmapSource),
                                                                    typeof(MyViewer));

    public BitmapSource ProjectedImageSource
    {
        get => (BitmapSource)this.GetValue(ProjectedImageSourceProperty);
        set => this.SetValue(ProjectedImageSourceProperty, value);
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the ProjectedImageSource is null when called in the constructor (I've tried in the Loaded callback too) so I can't set the Changed event handler.

I'm aware there is a ValidateValue callback, but this needs to be a static static so won't work in this scenario.

Is there some trick I can use to make this functionality work, or is it fundamentally flawed to attempt this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should register a PropertyChangedCallback with dependency property metadata:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectedImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ProjectedImageSource),
        typeof(BitmapSource),
        typeof(MyViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(ProjectedImageSourceChanged));

private static void ProjectedImageSourceChanged(
    DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewer = (MyViewer)obj;

    viewer.imageModel3D.SetImage(e.NewValue as BitmapImage); // may not be a BitmapImage
}
```

Or shorter:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectedImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ProjectedImageSource),
        typeof(BitmapSource),
        typeof(MyViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            (o, e) => ((MyViewer)o).imageModel3D.SetImage(e.NewValue as BitmapImage)));
```

---

As a note, it seems unnecessary that your `IImageModel3D.SetImage` method requires a `BitmapImage` argument. Better use `BitmapSource` instead, and write your PropertyChangedCallback like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectedImageSourceProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ProjectedImageSource),
        typeof(BitmapSource),
        typeof(MyViewer),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            (o, e) => ((MyViewer)o).imageModel3D.SetImage((BitmapSource)e.NewValue)));
```

If SetImage really requires a BitmapImage, you should change the type of your dependency property.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, second form does exactly what I need